# Multiple resources in a terraform module - how to refer from main module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My terraform module structure looks like this.

```
├───dev
│       dev.auto.tfvars
│       main.tf
│       output.tf
│       variables.tf
│
└───modules
    ├───instances
    │       main.tf
    │       output.tf
    │       variables.tf
    │       versions.tf
    │
    └───networking
            main.tf
            output.tf
            variables.tf
            versions.tf
```

My learning objective is to add aws_vpc,aws_subnet under networking module.
networking (main.tf)

```
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block = var.cidr_block
  instance_tenancy = "default"
  enable_dns_hostnames = var.enable_dns_hostnames
  enable_dns_support = var.enable_dns_support
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnets" {
  cidr_block = var.private_subnets
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  availability_zone = var.az
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnets" {
  cidr_block = var.public_subnets
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  availability_zone = var.az
}
```

I'm referring this from my dev(main.tf)

```
module "vpc_subnets" {
  source = "../modules/networking"
  cidr_block = var.vpc_cidr_block
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support = true
  az = var.az

}
```

But I can't understand how to refer/call to resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnets" and resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnets" in my dev (main.tf) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your module has to **output** values that you want to use in your `dev (main.tf)`. For example:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block = var.cidr_block
  instance_tenancy = "default"
  enable_dns_hostnames = var.enable_dns_hostnames
  enable_dns_support = var.enable_dns_support
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnets" {
  cidr_block = var.private_subnets
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  availability_zone = var.az
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnets" {
  cidr_block = var.public_subnets
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  availability_zone = var.az
}

output "public_subnets" {
   value = aws_subnet.public_subnets
}

output "private_subnets" {
   value = aws_subnet.private_subnets
}
```

then in your `dev (main.tf)` your refer to them as

```
module "vpc_subnets" {
  source = "../modules/networking"
  cidr_block = var.vpc_cidr_block
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support = true
  az = var.az
}

# for example:

locals {
  my_public_subnet_id = module.vpc_subnets.public_subnets.id
  my_private_subnet_id = module.vpc_subnets.private_subnets.id
}
```